# itextsharp: how do i add another page to the document and start writing to it?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

how do i add another page to the document and start writing to it in vb.net please

Comment: You've been down this road before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940352/itextsharp-how-do-i-add-a-new-page-and-write-to-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've got something like `Dim document As New Document(...)` in your code, just call `document.newPage()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `NewPage` method of the `iTextSharp.Text.Document` class normally does this.  What happens when you use that?